# Sort huge file with low RAM on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, fs

We have 500GB file with integer rows.
How we can sort it with only 512Mb RAM using Node.js?
I think something like that:

1. Break main file on chunks by 256Mb
2. Sort every chunk
3. Get first row of every chunk, sort and push it to final file
4. Do the 3th step for every rows in chunks.

Some ideas?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to user [some-random-it-boy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9248718/some-random-it-boy)
This solution based on child-process with native sort util.
I think it should work)

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    sort = spawn('sort', ['in.txt']);

var writer = fs.createWriteStream('out.txt');

sort.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  writer.write(data)
});

sort.on('exit', function (code) {
  if (code) console.log(code); //if some error
  writer.end();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried anything like you describe first? Stack Overflow is much better at solving specific programming problems rather than large goals/ projects.

Comment: aren't streams one of the defining features of node? you could look into `createReadStream` and `createWriteStream`

Comment: @Sheraff now I'm using `fs.openSync`, `fs.readSync` and `fs.writeSync` but can't understand algorithm for to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate to give a non-js solution to a js question. But since you are using the node environment why not delegate this task to a process that has been designed just for that?

With your package [child-process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), call the `sort` ([docs here](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)) command with whatever parameters you need.

Quoting from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68171):

> According to the [algorithm](http://vkundeti.blogspot.com/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html) used by sort, it will use memory according to what is available: half of the biggest number between TotalMem/8 and AvailableMem. So, for example, if you have 4 GB of available mem (out of 8 GB), sort will use 2GB of RAM. It should also create many 2 GB files in /bigdisk and finally merge-sort them.

Which essentially was what you suggested doing, already implemented and in C running on bare hardware without any interpreters in between. I guess you can't get faster than that within your constraints :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Add solution based on your answer to main thread

Answer (score 0):

If your intergers are not too big you could try too convert them into strings, compare them with a custom comparator and convert afterwards back to integer.
**Background**: JS needs for numbers (e.g. integers) 64-bit and uses for strings a set of "elements" of 16-bit unsigned integer values. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

I don't know if this really helps with memory and if it's
worth the effort but perhaps it helps.